# JSON files have missing quote marks (")

Tags: neovim

When I open a file in Neovim, the quote marks are hidden.

Below is a valid `.json` file. As you can see, quotemarks only appear with empty strings

[image]

The quotes are hidden but they exist if I use HJKL and encounter them - sometimes I have to press L twice to move right, even though the selected character doesnt change.

This is very annoying. How do I make the quotes appear again?

Answer (score 3):

Same problem I noticed caused by Yggdroot/indentLine.

```
use { 'Yggdroot/indentLine' } -- adds vertical lines along indentations but screws up JSON by removing quotes
```

Toggling show indentation lines makes the quotes reappear. Will post a solution if I every take the time to implement one.

See ticket: https://github.com/Yggdroot/indentLine/issues/172

The problem is this ticket was closed prematurely. The suggestion below does not work:

## This Solution does not work

See comments:

> yes, this issue shouldn't be closed, let g:vim_json_syntax_conceal = 0 still doesn't work

vimscript

```
let g:vim_json_syntax_conceal = 0
```

or lua

```
lua vim.g.vim_json_syntax_conceal = 0
```

## Subpar "Solution" (actually a Workaround)

Disable the plugin when opening JSON

```
autocmd Filetype json let g:indentLine_setConceal = 0
```

**Disclaimer** I stopped using the plugin because of this. I deemed it too unreliable for my work.

Comment: Weird choice for a plugin to hide things like these as a default behavior!

Answer (score 2):

**One time fix**:
`:set conceallevel=0` - this makes the quotes appear again, but you need to write it everytime you open a json file

---

**Permanent fix**:
This was caused by the `lukas-reineke/indent-blankline.nvim` plugin for me. [If using neovim,   make sure to use the `lua` branch of this plugin, not `master` (github issue link)](https://github.com/lukas-reineke/indent-blankline.nvim/issues/77).

I use the `paq` plugin manager so I needed to do this in my `init.lua`

```
paq 'lukas-reineke/indent-blankline.nvim'  
paq { 'lukas-reineke/indent-blankline.nvim', branch='lua' }
```

[Relevant commit in my dotfiles](https://github.com/3nuc/dotfiles/commit/a3504b58e747a7742d8a7fbc24cd315a990ec083)

---

Answer (score 0):

Uses Neovim's virtual text feature and **no conceal.**
Use lukas-reineke/indent-blankline.nvim, instead use Yggdroot/indentLine.
With indentline by lukas-reineke, your json file should be fine with another work.